# Permission Denied error while downloading file from Dropbox in Python

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

Through the metadata of one folder, I am able to get relative file paths of the files I want to download to my local machine. When I give this path to source code of `do_get()`, it gives me permission denied error. Here is the code which is supposed to download files and decrypt them but its not able to download the files on the first hand.

```
  @command
  def do_decryptFiles(self, from_path, to_path, key):
    """
    Decrypt all the files given in the folder and subfolders of from_path 

    Examples:
    Dropbox> decryptFiles '/Photos' 'E:\temp' 'a13223132323232' 
    """

    folder_metadata = self.api_client.metadata(from_path)
    print "metadata:", folder_metadata
    for s in folder_metadata['contents']:
        if(s['is_dir'] == True):
            print "directory:", s['path']
        else:
            FFPath = s['path'] 
            print FFPath
            do_get(self, from_path, to_path)
            to_file = open(os.path.abspath(to_path), "wb")
            f, metadata = self.api_client.get_file_and_metadata(self.current_path + FFPath)
            to_file.write(f.read())
```

When it calls `open()`, command line gives me Permission Denied error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example/cli_client.py", line 397, in <module>
    main()
  File "example/cli_client.py", line 394, in main
    term.cmdloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 219, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "example/cli_client.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args)
  File "example/cli_client.py", line 315, in do_decryptFiles
    to_file = open(os.path.abspath(to_path), "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\proto'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a local directory permissions issue? I had similar problem recently, if it is there are some possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461404/permission-denied-to-other-app-after-makedirs/15461928#15461928).

It sounds to me like this isn't a Dropbox API issue, it's a local IO Error.