# Permission Denied to Other App after makedirs()

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I have a Python app running on a server which is creating folders like this

```
    if not os.path.exists(destinationPath):
        os.makedirs(destinationPath, 777)
```

I have a client app (also in Python) uploading files to the server via SFTP using the [Paramiko module](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). The client also creates folders on the server if needed like this

```
    makeCommand = 'mkdir -p "' + remotePath + '"'
        ssh.exec_command(makeCommand)
```

and this works fine. The problem I'm having is that if the server app makes a folder, the client doesn't have access to that folder (can't upload to it or create subfolders). I get the following error

```
   line 104, in upload
ftMan.sftp.put(localFile, remoteFile)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 565, in put
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 245, in open
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 635, in _request
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 682, in _read_response
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 710, in _convert_status
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How can I have each app create folders that the other can use also? I've tried setting permissions (as you can see in the first piece of code for the server above) but this doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Whenever you write a script that creates files with `777` permissions, a kitten dies.

Comment: Ha, @BurhanKhalid , I'm using 777 just to check if it will work, will change to more suitable permission later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar question question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231901/permission-problems-when-creating-a-dir-with-os-makedirs-python) and it turns out the mode argument in `os.makedirs()` is ignored on some systems. You need to use `os.chmod` to get around this.
For folders created I'm now doing

```
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(theDirectory):
        os.chmod(dirpath, 0777)
```

occasionally to change all permissions in created folders. This has solved to problem and the client app can interact with folders created by the server app.

Comment: For anyone using Python3, you will have to replace 0777 with 0O777, to accommodate the way Python3 handles Octal numbers. 

[source](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/58225003.html#:~:text=Os%20chmod%20invalid%20token,3%20friendly%20%2C%20line%2061%20os.&text=This%20error%20means%20the%20octal,of%20%220%22%3B%20share.)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `os.makedirs` says:

> The default mode is 0777 (octal).

You are passing 777, which is a totally different number thanks to the lack of leading 0 to indicate octal.  You should probably just not pass the mode at all, and let it use the default.

Comment: The default leads to the same problem. You are right about the missing leading 0, I will need to add that. But even default mode leaves me with the same error when attempting to upload.

Comment: Can you check what mode it's actually ending up with in both cases?

Comment: Both cases (passing 0777 or passing nothing) seem to be creating a folder with permission 755?

Comment: And what about when the client creates it?  And what about the owner & group set on the directories in both cases?  Your first task here should be to discern what is actually the visible difference between when the client creates the directory vs. when the server does.

Comment: It seems the mode parameter is ignored on some systems. So regardless of what is passed for mode when creating a folder, the default is used. I'm using Debian Linux and this is happening. I had to use os.chmod() to change permissions after the folder is created. I posted an answer here. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot to set your [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).  Try this:

`os.umask(0)`

*before* you make any calls involving modes.

Comment: Thanks, would calling this once when the app starts up be sufficient, or would any class that is making calls involving modes need to call this also?

Comment: This *should* be process-wide.  It's a low-level interface to [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask)(2), which you should consult for corner and edge cases.  It is *not* object-oriented or otherwise "nice" in any meaningful way.